# Amazon SQS (Android) handle intermittent network connectivity

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to figure out how to handle intermittent network connectivity in regards to Amazon SQS on Android.  I need to send messages every 10 minutes (or so) and would like any messages that cannot be delivered due to network issues be sent at the earliest time when the network is restored. My hosted service orders messages so getting a few queued messages at once is no issue, but having messages be completely dropped is a problem.

AFAIK, my retry policy is set to retry up to 25 times and then give up.  Obviously this is not a great solution, but I didn't see any hooks for network connectivity callbacks or any option to have it retry when the connection is restored if the cause of the error is due to network issues.

The only alternative I can think of (using what I know about this API) is to implement a VERY long-lasting back off strategy and hope the user gets network again with X amount of time, but that seems incorrect.

```
ClientConfiguration ccfg = new ClientConfiguration();
            ccfg.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy(null, null, 25, false));
            AmazonSQSClient client = new      
AmazonSQSClient(params[0].credentialsProvider, ccfg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the retry policy is not going to help you in this case.

What you might need to do is:

1. Cache sqs messages when network is not reachable on mobile.(either file or db).
2. Implement a network change listener on android and trigger sqs calls when the networks changes from unreachable to reachable.

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html